# response.setheader("Refresh", "0") not working

Tags: java, html, servlets, httprequest

I am trying to refresh my webpage when user session has expired or the connection is not active. I tried a lot of codes but it didn't seem to work. The last code that I used is

```
if(session.getAttribute("connection") != null && !session.getAttribute("connection").equals("")){
            conn = (DBConnection) session.getAttribute("connection");
            if(conn == null){
                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    response.setHeader("Refresh", "3");
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.setHeader("Refresh", "3");
                return;
            }
```

I also tried response.sendRedirect() and request.getrequestdispatcher.forward() but it didnt work as well. the servlet is being called by a javascript which expects a json object.

Comment: you are accessing HttpSession when it is actually expired?

Comment: Refresh meta tags and headers will only work if you are sending back a html document the agent is going to interpret. It sounds like you are just sending back some data that is being used by javascript. If that is the case then the javascript will need to trigger the agent to do a page refresh.

Comment: In your code what is the purpose of the If condition? Simply you can add `response.setContentType("text/html");` and `response.setHeader("Refresh", "3");`

Comment: thanks @BevynQ. but is there a way that I can trigger the html file that calls the javascript through the servlet?

Comment: @Oneb and ling.s actually the program works. Im just doing some modifications like adding refresh

Comment: Did you try `response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 3);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly execute a command on the client directly from the servlet. Notice that `http protocol` relies on requests from the client and responses from the server.

So if no request is made from the client, then nothing can be send from the server  (simply because the server doesn't have a request to response )

I know you have seen this functionality and yes it can be done. But not in this manner. Ajax is your best bet here... (sending requests at regular intervals and getting response back from server etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a page to be refreshed use the following meta tag in the page header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```